# Why same internal ip and external ip?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, virtual-machines

I obtained a virtual server(running ubuntu 11.01) in a cloud with 1 static ip. I tried to ifconfig so as to obtain internal IP and also for the external ip I used http://whatismyipaddress.com/
All of the returned the same value for IP. This means my external and internal IPs are the same. How can I change this?Is there anywhere I have to configure in the linux environment?
Thanks

Comment: What.. I don't even.. what!?

Comment: Why do you need an internal IP on this system, and internal to *what* if it's hosted?

Comment: There is no "internal" or "external" IP... it's just *the* IP assigned to the machine.

Comment: And why would whatismyip return anything BUT your external IP...if you're querying through the external IP? External sites don't know your system's configuration. If it did, you should be very afraid.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, just maybe, your server isn't running through a NAT.